# Convolution product on the linear dual of the polynomial algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, convolution, hopf-algebras

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field and let us consider the $\Bbbk$-algebra $\Bbbk[X]$ of polynomials in one indeterminate with its natural Hopf algebra structure, i.e.
$$\Delta(X)=X\otimes 1+1\otimes X, \quad s(X)=-X\quad \text{and} \quad \varepsilon(X)=0 .$$
On its linear dual $\Bbbk[X]^*$ we may define the convolution product by
$$(f*g)(X^n)=\sum_{i+j=n} \binom{n}{i}f(X^i)g(X^j)$$
for all $f,g\in\Bbbk[X]^*$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let 
$$\Bbbk[X]^\circ=\left\{f\in\Bbbk[X]^*\mid f\left(X^kp(X)\right)=0\textrm{ for all }k\in\mathbb{N}\textrm{ and some }p(X)\in\Bbbk[X]\right\}$$
be the finite dual of $\Bbbk[X]$. In different but equivalent words, $\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ is the $\Bbbk$-subalgebra of $\Bbbk[X]^*$ of all those $f$ which vanishes on a finite-codimensional ideal of $\Bbbk[X]$.

**Question:** Can we claim that if $f*g\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ and $f\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ then $g\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ as well?

**Equivalently:** If a product $f∗g$ and one of its factors $f$ vanish on an ideal of finite codimension, is it necessarily true that the other factor $g$ also vanishes on an ideal of finite codimension?

P.S.: the question is strictly related with [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263964/linear-topologies-on-the-finite-dual-of-the-polynomial-algebra) on MO, but with a less technical taste (I hope). My thanks to KonKan for helping in clarifying the question.

Comment: Just to clarify the question for myself: in simpler terms, $\Bbb k [X] ^\circ$ is the set of linear forms that are $0$ on some non-zero ideal of $\Bbb k [X]$. Is $\Bbb k[X] ^\circ$ an ideal in $(\Bbb k[X]^*, +, *)$? If so, then it seems that you are asking whether $\Bbb k[X] ^\circ$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: They are linear forms that vanish on a non-zero ideal in fact. If you know the terminology, $\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ is the finite dual of $\Bbbk[X]$ (AKA Sweelder or restricted dual). It is a $\Bbbk$-subalgebra. It cannot be an ideal as $1_{\Bbbk[X]^*}=\varepsilon\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$. What I'm asking may sound like: "We have a subalgebra $B$ of an algebra $A$. We know that a product belongs to $B$. Is it true that the factors belong to $B$ as well?". However, in this generality of course it is false: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\pi\cdot(1/\pi)\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AlexM. I beg your pardon, I realized just now that maybe you would need some more details. Both $\Delta$ and $\varepsilon$ are algebra morphisms: they can be defined using the universal property of polynomials for example. Thus, $\ker(\varepsilon)=\langle X \rangle$ and so $\varepsilon\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$. In light of this it should be also clearer why $\varepsilon=1_{\Bbbk[X]^*}$ with respect to the convolution product.

Comment: I realized also that if $f\in\Bbbk[X]^*\setminus \Bbbk[X]^\circ$ is convolution invertible then obviously $f*f^{-1}\in \Bbbk[X]^\circ$. I edited the question to avoid this case.

Comment: Do you mean that for any element $\phi\in\mathbb{k}[X]^\circ$ and any factorization $\phi=f*g$, one of the two factors (either $f$ or $g$) has to lie        inside $\mathbb{k}[X]^\circ$ ?

Comment: Or are you asking whether for any $\phi\in\mathbb{k}[X]^\circ$ there is at least one factorization having this property (and this is why you are excluding the "obvious" factorization $\phi=1*\phi$) ?

Comment: None of the two actually. I have an element $\phi\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ which I know from other ways that can be written as $\phi=f*g$ for some $f,g\in\Bbbk[X]^*$. Actually, I even know that $f\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$. I would like to know if we can claim that $g\in\Bbbk[X]^\circ$ as well or not.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: aahh.. i think i got it better now. But if this is the case, i think your OP does not clearly reflect your last comment (at least not in my understanding). Maybe you should edit your OP to become more clear.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback. I'll try to think about it for a while and i'll try to come back.

Comment: So your question might be rephrased like: "if a product $f*g$ and one of its factors $f$ vanish on an ideal of finite codimension, is it necessarily true that the other factor $g$ also vanishes on an ideal of finite codimension"   ? Is this the case or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Thank you very much for your effort: I'll edit the question with your formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative answer finally has been given to this question. I'm grateful to JJR because his/her answer to the [following related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238053/linearly-recursive-sequences?noredirect=1#comment4602243_2238053) solved the problem once for all.

Let $\xi:\Bbbk[X]\to\Bbbk$ be given by $\xi(X^n)=\delta_{n,1}$ (in some sense, $\xi$ is the dual of the basis element $X$), and consider $g:\Bbbk[X]\to \Bbbk$ be given by $g(X^n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then
$$(\xi*g)(X^n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\xi(X^k)g(X^{n-k})=\cases{ng(X^{n-1}) =1\quad\,\, n\geq 1 \\
0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad n=0}$$
It follows that $\langle X^2-X\rangle\subseteq \ker{(\xi*g)}$ and $\langle X^2\rangle\subseteq \ker(\xi)$, so both $\xi$ and $\xi*g$ belong to $\Bbbk[X]^\circ$, but $g$ does not (the associated sequence is not linearly recursive, as it is the harmonic sequence).