# Linearly recursive sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the field of complex numbers and consider the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of all infinite sequences $(s_n)$ of complex numbers. It is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with the Hurwitz product
$$(s_n)* (t_n)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}s_kt_{n-k}\right)$$
and unit $(1,0,0,\ldots)$. Recall that a sequence is called *linearly recursive* if there exist $r>0$ and $h_1,\ldots,h_{r}\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$s_n=h_1s_{n-1}+h_2s_{n-2}+\cdots+h_rs_{n-r} \quad \textrm{for all}\quad n\geq r.$$
Denote by $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C})\subseteq \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ the $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra of all linearly recursive sequences and consider the distinguished sequence $(e_n)$ defined by $e_1=1$ and $e_n=0$ otherwise, i.e. $$(e_n):=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}).$$

> **Q:** If $(e_n)*(s_n)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C})$, does it follow that $(s_n)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C})$?

Caveat: multiplying by $(e_n)$ does not simply mean "shifting" the sequence as one may expect. For example, $(e_n)*(e_n)=(0,0,2,0,\ldots)$.

NB: this question is strictly connected with [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191124/convolution-product-on-the-linear-dual-of-the-polynomial-algebra) by myself (see e.g. Peterson and Taft's *The Hopf algebra of linearly recursive sequences*). However, this formulation has a totally different flavor and it is addressed to a different audience. This is why I decided to open a new question instead of editing the previous one.

Comment: Is harmonic sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots)$ linearly recursive?

Comment: Great observation, chapeau! In fact, it is not linearly recursive. Do you mind to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(e_n) \ast (s_n) = (0,s_0,2s_1,3s_3,\dots).$ If $(s_n) = (1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots)$ is a harmonic sequence, then $$(e_n) \ast (s_n) = (0,s_0,2s_1,3s_3,\dots) = (0,1,1,1,\dots).$$ Since the latter is linearly recursive and the harmonic sequence $(s_n)$ is not linearly recursive, $(e_n)*(s_n)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}) \not\Rightarrow (s_n)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C})$.